# MS SQL (2014) slow query vs. comments in the code

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, comments

I have query like this:

1. select into table2 from table1
2. select function(table2.field1) from table2
3. lot of commented code

Whole query runs about 25s. Running it separately - (1) and next (2) it runs (altogether) about 3s. After removing comments (3) whole query runs 3s too. Adding (redo) comments again - 25s. The function from (2) converts UTC datetime to local time and operates on its own variables and calculations only (no queries to any tables, views, ect.). When i remove this function (select table2.field1 without calculations) it runs 3s - no mather if comments are present or not

I can say, that this issue is related to one of two servers only.
Very strange.
Any idea?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. When asking about performance issues you need to provide details for others. Things like the function code, table definitions etc. There just isn't enough information currently to offer any real help.

Answer (score 0):

Additional info:

I have replaced the funkcion (another one) - this same. I have noticed that query runs as long as size of comments. I have added comments to 700 rows - almost 50s, 350 rows of comments - 26s, 170 rows - 14s. Comments placed in the top or at the bottom - no matter.
It looks like all comments was processed by function some way... What on earth!?